# Is it possible to edit TCP and UDP packets?

Tags: tcp, udp

Is it possible to edit the UDP and TCP packets a program sends? For example, we have a program that sends some information to its server. But we don't want to send some information that might be sensitive, so we'd like to edit the packets the program sends.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  This is not a simple task, it would usually require writing some kind of driver that hooks into the network stack at which point you would have to interpret all of the protocols you would want to tamper with.

Comment: Also depending on what you are wanting to monitor there are also other ways to handle this on higher levels than TCP and UDP (for example the program uses HTTP to communicate to the server there a million and one various outbound transparent proxy softwares out there can can monitor all content). We need more detail about what kind of sofware and what sorts of things are you trying to detect unless you are happy with the answer "Yes, you can. Go find the proper software to do it".

Comment: @heavyd I'm using Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: IP/UDP transmission units are called datagrams, and TCP are segments, by the way. Packets are a higher-level concept that can include things unrelated to Internet Protocol (e.g. part of an Ethernet frame).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain We are talking about a program like a simple chatting application. it just connect to the server (and of course there are some proxies between us) and send a message with the sensitive data (like data about system hashing algorithm for example) and we want to edit these pockets.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman depending on what you said, we should do this task with some higher-level than the pockets one instructions and programs?

Comment: What I meant by that is that the TCP or UDP part of a packet is only a small portion of it. If you intercept a packet using a packet sniffer, you are only really going to be interested in part of the IP payload portion. It will still have the same destination, etc. Really the best way to do this might be to inject something into `ws2_32.dll` of a running program and alter sent data before it is even constructed into a packet... but that is a very technical thing to do. I found a question on Stack Overflow that [outlines this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190275/c-hooking-winsock).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I just confused about it. isn't there any program-based method? because as you said, I should have a lot of knowledge to inject the dll and of course it is not possible to do it on the customers windows. because we may make some privacy add-ons to protect the users privacy.

Comment: there is a program called netsed, I haven't used it before, and it's *nix based so you'd have a little linux machine with two interfaces doing it.

Comment: @barlop isn't there any application for Windows platform?

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri apparently 'bit twist' can take a pcap file, and change bytes, http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/doc/bittwiste.1.html it has a -D option delete byte at an offset, that lets you delete anything, and apparently it lets you replay the edit, so,send it out, but i'm not sure how /if one can get it to listen and act as a proxy..so it takes actual traffic rather than just a pcap file. and not a copy of actual traffic but the actual traffic itself